# Hyperledger composer angular app using yeoman generator

Tags: angular, yeoman-generator, hyperledger-composer, npm-start

I am able to create angular app project using yeoman generator for hyperledger composer.

Getting below error while running angular app generated by yeoman generator
command: npm start.

> ERROR in multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:4200
>   ./src/main.ts  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:4200' in
>   '/home/praval/composer-sample-networks/packages/marbles-network/myapp'

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is due to an earlier error (not seen this error before) but I'm not sure. We will need more information to debug.

Comment: I think it was the version issue. My user specific npm version was 5.3. I changed it back to 3.10.10 and it worked. Thanks Dan.